# How to convert ArrayList<subClass> to ArrayList<super> in java

Tags: java, arraylist

I hava a method `setData(ArrayList<super> list)`, so anyone who want set data can have their own entity, just need to extends from super class. but when they call `setData`, how they convert ArrayList to ArrayList?

Now i use setData(new ArrayList(list)), but it's not a good solution.

Anyone can tell me how to convert or another solution can avoid the problem. Very appreciated!

Comment: Maybe `ArrayList<? extends super> list`?

Comment: Thanks, this `setData(ArrayList<? extends SuperType> list)` is what i want.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do with the list afterwards. If you're just going to read from it, you can declare your method like this:

```
setData(ArrayList<? extends SuperType> list)
```

You can't add anything to that list, though, because you won't know what `?` is. Another option is to create a copy when calling your method:

```
List<SubType> subtypeList = ...;
setData(new ArrayList<SuperType>(subtypeList));
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of coding

```
setData(new ArrayList(list));
```

you could simply use

```
setData((ArrayList<super>)((Object)list));
```

Casting list to Object first and then to ArrayList will force the compiler to accept the method invocation.  As an added bonus, you don't suffer the performance expense of creating a new array list.